# MongoDB accent insensitive queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How should I do case insensitive and accent insensitive queries in MongoDB?

Example: 
A search for "sandalias" should return results like "sandálias"

For now my query is only case insensitive:

```
name :  {     $regex: word,
              $options: "i"
        };
```

I'm using MeteorJS my mongo version doesnt supports collations

Comment: @felix I'm using MeteorJS my mongo version doesnt supports collations

Comment: @MMrj i'd suggest editing your q to include this important information

Comment: what's you mongodb server version ?

Comment: @felix probably not quite, since your own answer there does not actually show usage of a [`$text` search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/). There are options on a `$text` search though that allow this. You could include that in the answer.

Comment: There is no reason why you cannot use a separate server instance with meteor. In fact, you have to deploy at some point and that is exactly what is going to happen. Pointing your meteor app at an external server is an easy exercise.

Comment: @NeilLunn **`$text`** is diacritic insensitive by default since MongoDB 3.2. I'll update my answer to mention this

Comment: @felix Please do. Also include a text search example and not just and equality search example and I will be happy to point there as a duplicate. Already voted on it BTW, since there is no other answer pointing out the usage.